# wiredep confusion and wiredep didn't inject after filename rename

Tags: gulp, wiredep

So I made an application with yo gulp-angular. An example app that got added is modernizr. I'm trying to understand how wiredep injects the js file into the index.html. I know it uses

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- endbower -->
```

After running gulp, wiredep added this code to index.html

```
<script src="../bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
```

Now, I renamed modernizr.js physical file to avengermodernizr.js just to see how wiredep will behave and if it will inject. Unfortunately, wiredep didn't inject it into index.html. That's when I got confused. I can't find how it's injecting a specific filename.

So could there be a configuration file that modernizr is telling to wiredep?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no, `wiredep` uses the file(s) specified in packages' `main` property from their `bower.json`. (See the [bower.json spec on the main property](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec#main))

If the package does not have a `bower.json` (like in the case of Modernizr) or does not supply the `main` property, `wiredep` will try and inject a file that matches the package's name. In this case, there is a file called `modernizr.js` in the root directory of what gets downloaded when you `bower install modernizr`, and since that file name matches the package's name, it injects that file.

Also, you should not be renaming bower files. That defeats the purpose of a package manager.

Comment: I'm aware that I should not be renaming the filenames. I would just curious if wiredep was using a wildcard like *.js. Based from my test, it didn't. Now I know that it will use the package's name. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: oh, am I right that wiredep will go inside each package that is mentioned in the bower.json file?

Comment: Yes. If you use `bower install` without the `--save` flag, and thus that package is not in your `bower.json`, it will not inject it.

Comment: what should we do if we have javascript files from different packages and we want a specific order when they get injected? Same thing goes with css files, I want dependency.css to be loaded first before final.css. Thanks!

Comment: You list `dependency.css` as a dependency of `final.css` in the package that contains `final.css`. If these are 3rd party packages that don't specify their dependencies and *should*, open a ticket against that package. Otherwise, you can use the `overrides` mechanic from `wiredep`.